# SQL join in Laravel, how to?

Tags: sql, laravel, join

Help me please, with JOINS, learning SQL and joins are painful :(

I have **table**: *categories* with column name: Name, ID

I have **table**: *sub_categories* with column name: ID

I have **table**: *provider_services* with column name: category_id & subcategory_id

When I do in laravel view blade `{{$provider->providerServices()->where("status",1)->count()}}`

I will receive: 2

It means, that provider, has 2 services with category_id 2, 3 and subcategory_id 4,8

Question:
How can I join this data to table categories and grab the category Name using cat_id & subcat_id?

- Category_id 2 is - Painting
- Category_id 3 is - Plumbing
- SubCategory_id is - Aqua
- SubCategory_id 8 is - Test

So, as A result I need to have something: Painting and Aqua, Plumbing and Test

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner Join Clause

The query builder may also be used to write join statements. To perform a basic "inner join", you may use the join method on a query builder instance. The first argument passed to the join method is the name of the table you need to join to, while the remaining arguments specify the column constraints for the join. You can even join to multiple tables in a single query:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins

The above example can easily be changed to work for you. 
The join function for is made the following:

```
->join('table', 'column1', '=', 'column2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange, why this SQL query, return overall status of Categories & Sub-Categories, but not status of provider_services?

```
SELECT categories.name, categories.id, sub_categories.id as idPodKa, sub_categories.name as ImjaPodkategorij, provider_services.status as Status
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN sub_categories 
ON categories.id=sub_categories.category_id 
LEFT JOIN provider_services
ON categories.id=sub_categories.category_id=provider_services.status
where provider_services.status = 1
```